# Special case of: Fixed / Floating Sidebar Element

Tags: jquery, scroll, css-position, floating

### The Situation:

I have a pretty regular sidebar on my website.

As the last element in the sidebar you can see the Blogroll.

Below this I need to create **a similar container** which only contains a **scroll-to-top button**.

Pretty easy so far.

---

### The Problem:

I need the Button to behave the following way:

- If you **scroll down and this container (only this) approaches the upper
  edge** of the visible area I need it to **stay there**
  (position:fixed?) and move down with you. (With a little offset to
  the top)
- If the you scroll up again it moves up with you. But it has to **stop when it gets to its old position.**
- It needs to **stop before the footer** begins.

---

### How far am I?

I know a bit of jquery but am no master.

Is such a thing actually possible?

I am happy to attach special classes to the container to make it work. At the moment I am just not sure how to approach this.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure about the availability of plugins, but I have seen such behaviours implemented in many sites. You need to keep track of a few variables. First is the [scrollTop](http://jqapi.com/#p=scrollTop) to find where the page is scrolling vertically, second is the position of the button via [offset](http://jqapi.com/#p=offset). Keeping track of these 2 variables using page [scroll](http://jqapi.com/#p=scroll) will help you to determine when to set the css attributes of the button. You'll need to change the css `position` to and from `fixed` with proper offset.

Comment: You are most welcomed.